# Problem when extracting the structure of DB2 (Back up Structure)

Tags: backup, restore, db2, authorization

I want to extract the structure of a 9.7 DB2 database to use to clone it but some of the authorization statements are missing afterwards:
I tried something like this:

```
db2look -d dbName -a -x -o db2look.sql
```

what I noticed, is that the *Authorization Statements on User Defined Functions* and *Stored Procedures* are missing.

I expected to see something like this: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC65658

EDIT: A try indicated, that this command correctly extracted the `GRANT`statements on the productive system.

Answer (score 0):

`GRANT` statements will only be extracted if they were ever explicitly issued against database objects, e.g. `GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION myfunc TO USER whoever`. Implicit privileges will not be extracted, because technically they were never `GRANT`ed.

Comment: The rights were given to the users/roles explicitly.